# hausdorff distance in python of 2xN matrices with different number of columns

Tags: python, matrix, scipy, scipy-spatial

I have two 2xN matrices of values and I want to find the hausdorff distance of them using "directed_hausdorff(u,v)" function. However, since the number of columns are not equal in both matrices I want to find the hausdorff distance of using the matrices with the lower number of columns. For example if I have

```
t = [(1,2,3,9), (4,5,6,7)] 
l = [(3,4,5), (7,8,9)]
```

`l` has 3 columns and `t` has 4 columns. Since `t` is bigger than `l` I would like to modify `t` so that it is instead the same size of `l` so that I may compute the hausdorff distance between to equally sized matrices, essentially becoming

```
t = [(1,2,3), (4,5,6)]
l = (3,4,5), (7,8,9)]
```

I would like to apply this to any two matrices of 2xN (different sizes) where I determine which matrix has more columns and then modify the larger matrix by eliminating elements starting from the last column so that it would equal the size of the smaller matrix. Is there a shortcut method to do this that will output the two lists themselves?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of an existing function for this, but if `t` and `l` were Numpy arrays then you could accomplish this with fairly short code and without duplicating the data in memory.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial.distance import directed_hausdorff

...

t = np.array(t)
l = np.array(l)
num_cols = min(t.shape[1], l.shape[1])
distance = directed_hausdorff(t[:, :num_cols], l[:, :num_cols])
```

The expression `t.shape[1]` means the size of the array along dimension (or "axis") 1, i.e. the number of columns (whereas the number of rows would be `t.shape[0]`). The indexing syntax `t[:, :num_cols]` means for every row ("`:`"), get the first `num_cols` columns ("`:num_columns`"). The comma separates the range of indices for each dimension.